# Problem Unzipping huge zip file

Tags: zip, archive

I have issues unzipping a huge zip files containing around 1M files. The zip file is 15GB and uncompresses to ~60GB. When I run `unzip file.zip -d /directory/to/unzip/at` it uncompresses halfway and gives up at around 700K files. No error messages.

Any tips?

Comment: use 7zip to uncompress it

Comment: Same results, I tried with 7za

Answer (score 0):

I suspect **urilimit** set limit for either file size or CPU time:
[urilimit man page](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

Comment: They're both marked as "unlimited"

Comment: Does the unzipping stop at the exact same time?
Is the unzipped content with the same size every time?

Comment: The unzipping stops at the exact same file every single time. Also unzipping the content produces the same amount of files/size.

So you're right there seems to be a limiter. But it says "unlimited".

Comment: what filesystem are you decompressing the files to?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader ext4

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me (same symptoms, where it would hang after the same file every time). It turned out that stdout was being redirected somehow, so I wasn't seeing a prompt about overwriting a pre-existing file. Try running unzip with the `-o` option, and/or avoid stdout shenanigans.